# Checkboxes in table rows cant be clicked on

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, checkbox

I have a table that contains a list of alerts. Each row in the table is a unique alert. At the end of each row in the last cell is a checkbox.

We have a mechanism to indicate whether the item has been read (acknowledged). If it is read, the checkbox is checked, if not it is unchecked. The user has the ability to toggle this by clicking on the checkbox. The **ackCheckbox** method associated with the onchange event of the checkbox determines whether the checkbox is checked or not and then updates the rowId (passed in as the argument) as appropriate. The razor markup follows:

```
<td style="text-align: center" width="50">
    @if (al.UserAcknowledged)
    {
       sCheck = "checked='checked'"; //sCheck is defined outside the row loop
    }
   <input id="cb@(iCount)" name="cb@(iCount)" type="checkbox" @sCheck onchange="ackCheckbox('@(al.ID)')" />
</td>
```

When this renders, it renders as follows:

```
<td style="text-align: center" width="50">
     <input id="cb10" name="cb10" type="checkbox"  onchange="ackCheckbox('0c585aa0-bcd1-4eed-82a4-3fd4275eeffa')" />
</td>
```

Everything appears to be fine, however I am unable to click on the checkbox to change its state. It almost appears as if it is disabled. Does anyone have any ideas as to what is going on? Thanks in advance.

Comment: try temporarily removing the ackCheckbox function to see if it is the cause. Then if so, review that function.

Comment: I moved the column - made it the first column instead of the last column - it now seems to work. I am very puzzled.